# How can I change the default font color on ioslides across all slides?

Tags: r-markdown, ioslides

I did manage to change the font color locally using `<font color="orange">text</font>` and the font color of citations using `span.cite {color:blue;}`.

But I can't figure out how to change the default font color. Right now it's gray and I want it black.

Thank you!

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add at the top of your document:

```
<style type="text/css">
body p {
  color: #000000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. That put me back on track. I changed the color for a number of other tags such as h2, h3, li and span.MathJax, too. Now all is black.